# Connecting Scala with Hive Database using sbt for dependencies using IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, hive, sbt

I am having a very difficult time **connecting to hive database using Intellij** or basic Command line with scala ( would be happy with java too). I have in the past been able to connect to a MYSQL database by adding it on the library mysql-Connector. but I am unable somehow add a jar file to the project structure where it works.

and to make things abit more difficult. I have installed ubuntu with hive,spark, hadoop and I am connecting to it over the network.

**Is there someway I can add a depedency on the sbt file?**

Lastly, I know there are similar questions but they do not show in detail how to connect to a hive database from scala

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

```
`import java.sql.SQLException;
 import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.sql.ResultSet;
 import java.sql.Statement;
 import java.sql.DriverManager;
 object HiveJdbcClient extends App {
 val driverName = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
 Class.forName(driverName);
 val con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://http://192.168.43.64:10000/default", "", "");
 val stmt = con.createStatement();
 val tableName = "testHiveDriverTable";
 stmt.executeQuery("drop table " + "wti");
 var res = stmt.executeQuery("create table " + tableName + " (key int, value string)");
 // select * query
 var sql = "select * from " + tableName;
 res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
 while (res.next()) {System.out.println(String.valueOf(res.getInt(1)) + "\t" + res.getString(2));
 }
 // regular hive query
 sql = "select count(1) from " + tableName;
 res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
 while (res.next()) {
      System.out.println(res.getString(1));
 }
}`
```

Comment: Did you have a look to SBT documentation? Adding a library is quite straightforward: `libraryDependencies += "group" % "name" % "x.y.z"`

Comment: libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hive" % "hive-jdbc" % "3.1.2"    It is not working.

Comment: Looking at the project structure  there is nothing named "org.apache.hive.jdbc.Hivedriver" there  is something called "org.apache.hive:hive-jdbc:3.1.2" do I just change the driver name to that or something similar? @GaëlJ

Comment: please show us the `build.sbt` file or `project/Dependencies.scala` or `project/Build.scala` if you have one of them or all if you have all of them. (build.sbt is mandatory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The driver name is not correct for hive 3.1.2, it should be

```
org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
```

Cf https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r3.1.2/api/org/apache/hive/jdbc/HiveDriver.html

Comment: now beehive will not connect hive. unable to instate sessionhivemetastoreclient

Comment: Don't hesitate to open another question with details :-) as you can see, the devil is in the details !